# which rotation technique is mostly used in 3D graphic

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, rotation, blender

In 6 techniques: trigonometry, com-plex numbers, vectors, matrices, quaternions and multivectors. which roatation technieque is used mostly in 3D graphic? I read about these 6 techniques in Rotation Transforms for Computer Graphics book.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrices are mostly used at the lowest level since graphics hardware is optimized for matrix-vector multiplication. Quaternions are used a lot since they offer multiple advantages over matrices (like easy quaternion interpolation and averaging, singularity free representation,  simple re-normalization, faster rotation concatenation, etc). Frequently quaternions are converted to matrices and matrices to quaternions. Geometric Algebra Multivectors, mostly known as Rotors, are isomorphic to quaternions (basically no difference with them) just belong to a different algebra which subsume quaternions, however they are new to graphics people so not very popular yet, although GA users is growing quickly. Complex numbers they are used as well in the context of 3D non-euclidean geometry (e.g., hyperbolic geometry) and in 2D geometry of course. However not very used in 3D eiclidean geometry. Trigonometry is used a lot in 3D graphics, not exactly for rotations but for many other things is essential, like rendering, ilumination, etc. In summary they are all used. You definitely need to know matrices, vectors and trigonometry to succeed.